# ocultar key de google maps en pagina web

Tags: html, google-maps

Estoy probando una app y uso las librerías de google maps, pero al cargar el script en mi web principal si analizo el código se ve mi **key** de google maps.

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key="Mi key oculta"
```

Quisiera que en lugar de mi key original salga otro texto... ya que me da miedo que si libero mi app vayan a tomar la key y me la dañen

Answer (score 2):

Compañero, toda la configuración de seguridad de las API de Google se deben realizar en la consola de desarrollador de Google y dependiendo de la API que utilices, por ejemplo, para proteger el uso de la "Google Maps Javascript API" debes configurar las peticiones de acceso ya sea para que acepte peticiones desde algunas IP's o desde algunos dominios, una vez que restrinjas o filtres las peticiones que se hagan con tu API KEY no debes preocuparte por que sea pública ya que si no cumple con el filtro establecido para la petición no impactará en la cuota que tengas implementada.

Saludos.

Comment: Genial, mil gracias amigo por tu comentario... voy a revisarlas, no sabía de estas opciones.